# Swift 3: How can I show/hide the @IBAction button inside the ViewDidLoad() func?

Tags: uibutton, swift3, ibaction

I am trying to show/hide a button only if the information is available. For example, I get the information from the database, and if the field returns blank the a button should be hidden else show the button.

```
@IBAction func emailBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
   //blank
}


viewdidload()
if emailURL.characters.count >= 5
    {
        emailBtn.isHidden = false //Giving error Please see the screenshot
    }
    else
    {
        emailBtn.isHidden = true // Giving error Please see the screenshot
    }


}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHiNx.png)

Comment: the emailURL is the fields value that comes from the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to hide an @IBAction function. What you're intending to do is hide the button.  What you need to do is create an outlet in your code that references that button.

In the Storyboard, Control+Drag the button to your class. Create an outlet. This will create something like the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!
```

You want to reference that button in viewDidLoad()

```
myButton.isHidden = true
```

Comment: thanks, but then if i want to have a send email action on this button, will it be possible?

Comment: Yes. You don't have to remove the IBAction. That will be what happens when you press the button. But that's all the IBAction is: the action. It isn't the object itself.

Comment: I tried using the outlet and its keep on crashing. I created a private func check to see if the emailURL is valid or not and calling it in the view did load, but showing error

Comment: the error in the output panel is  **objc[14266]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x1239c2998) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x1237e7d38). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.**

Comment: First off, did you create the Outlet in the Storyboard as I mentioned? You can't just reference it in code without the Storyboard reference being created.

Comment: Second, it looks like that is a separate issue from the one in your question.

Comment: Okay. As for the error you have now, it looks like you have a conflict with the PLBuildVersion class. Either don't import one of those two frameworks (AssetsLibraryServices or PhotoLibraryServices), or, if you're writing that class yourself, rename it.